# Is it fine to add 100s of domains to single website in nginx

Tags: nginx

In nginx, we can set multiple domains to a single website like

```
server localhost abc.com def.com ghj.com
```

I want to keep 100s of domains that way.

The point is - we are auto generating websites. And we want to point all those domains to single website. Using the domain name/url, we want to send angular ajax requests which will fetch data related to that domain.

So, content will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a default server as a catch-all for any domain name that does not have an explicit `server_name`. For example:

```
server {
    listen  80  default_server;
    ...
}
```

You do not need to specify a `server_name` directive for default servers.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.